# Managing multiple google cloud VM instances / compute engines at the same time

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a few servers on google cloud. I made them in VM instances. They run the same script everyday but each server runs with different arguments.

However, when changes need to be made to them or updates, I have to do them one by one, all the changes are the same, only different arguments. Meaning I would ssh into the server, run apt updates, download some files, upload some files, change some arguments and test. Then I repeat this process on all the servers.

I would like to be able to keep one copy of the server somewhere which would upload to the rest, or make changes that would apply automatically to each server.

Is there some way I can achieve this? Update all the servers (apt update, or download new files or make changes to scripts) all at once?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a managed instance group that uses an instance template to create the VMs. Then, you can [roll out updates to MIGs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups).

Comment: hi, I saw this, but if i do this, whenever I have to update the instances, I would have to create a new template, and if I did that all the individual settings on each server would be wiped out correct?

Comment: yes, if your new template will be created in such way to wipe out all the settings

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a startup script stored on [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#cloud-storage) and [apply](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptrunninginstances) it to the running instances.

Comment: I kind of need to see the feed back from the servers too